# Terminate tkinter process when "X" button is clicked (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, terminate, python-class

I am coding a small GUI project in python. While the process is running, if the user clicks the "X" button then I keep getting alerts like "app not responding" in python. After I built an app with the same program, the same things kept happening.

I tried using self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.root.destroy())
However, I keep getting errors like
"self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed error"
To attempt to fix this, I tried using a boolean conditional with "self.button.winfo_exists()" then destroy, but I still kept getting errors.

Is there any such way to terminate the process when the "X" button is clicked, specifically in a class def_ *init* _(self) initializer?

Here is an example:

```
# Import needed python modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading
import random


class TkinterGUI:

    # Construct Object with GUI and execute mainloop
    def __init__(self):
        # CONSTRUCT GRAPHICAL USER INTERFACE
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("HI")  # Title
        self.root.geometry("850x600")  # Window Size

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)  # Frame for tkinter GUI

        # Create title and position
        self.header = tk.Label(self.frame, text="HI", font=('Helvetica bold', 45))
        self.header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=2)

        # Create subtitle and position
        self.subheading = tk.Label(self.frame, text="HI",
                                   font=('Helvetica', 14))
        self.subheading.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        # The generated sentence that the user has to type

        # Button to create new test
        self.new_test_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="New Test", command=self.new_test)
        self.new_test_button.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)

        # Button to restart same test
        self.restart_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Restart", command=self.restart)
        self.restart_button.grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)

        self.frame.pack(expand=True)  # Make frame expandable

        self.running = False  # Boolean to determine if time thread is runninG

        self.root.mainloop()  # Initialize mainloop
        **self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.root.destroy())**
```

I am also running a second threaded process, so when I click the button it might not disconnect the threaded process.

Comment: I think a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would really help in your case.

Comment: Done @Tranbi do you think I should also include the threaded process that I mentioned?

Comment: Of course, at least a simplified version of it. Have you read the link shared above? In the current state, your code is not runnable. I can add the method `new_test` and `restart` myself (which I did) but it still doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also the titles are unnecessary here

Comment: @fibonacci_ostrich Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to terminate the program when the user closes your window, or something else?

Comment: yes @BentheCoder I would like to terminate the program when the user closes the window. I tried self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.root.destroy()), but it never worked

Comment: @fibonacci_ostrich Try importing the `sys` module and then calling `sys.exit()`.  This terminates your program.

Comment: @BentheCoder is there a way to determine if the window is clicked on -- is self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", SYS.EXIT()) the best way to do this -- I jus tried this it doesn't work

Comment: `self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", SYS.EXIT()) ` will immediately call `SYS.EXIT()`. You need to pass `SYS.EXIT` not `SYS.EXIT()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, that's correct.  Sorry about my mistake about the extra () at the end of SYS.EXIT.

Comment: Provide a [mre]. You don't need to process a close window event, because the ```mainloop()``` returns when there's no main window. Also the Python interpreter exits when all threads except daemon threads finish.